# Scala: How to treat an Any like an Array or Seq?

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a way to treat an Any as an Array or Seq and iterate over it, if possible.

Currently I have some code that looks like this, taking a sequence of Any's and flattening out any Traversable or Array objects contained.

```
def flattenAsStrings(as: Seq[Any]): Seq[String] = {
  val (travValued, other) = as.partition(a => classOf[Traversable[_]] isAssignableFrom(a.getClass))
  val (arrayValued, singleValued) = other.partition(a => a.isInstanceOf[Array[_]])
  val travStrings = travValued.map(_.asInstanceOf[Traversable[_]].map(_.toString)).flatMap(_.toList)
  val arrayStrings = arrayValued.map(_.asInstanceOf[Array[_]].map(_.toString)).flatMap(_.toList)
  singleValued.map(_.toString) ++ travStrings ++ arrayStrings
}
```

It feels like there mustr be a simpler way to do this in Scala, given implicit conversions and whatnot.  Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to force each element to a `Seq`, and then flatten them all at once.  `Array` has an implicit conversion to `Seq` and both `Seq` and `Traversable` have a `.toSeq` method. So we can do:

```
val t: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val a: Array[Int] = Array(4, 5, 6)
val other = "whatever"
val as: Seq[Any] = List(t, a, other)

as.flatMap{
  case t: Traversable[_] => t.toSeq
  case a: Array[_] => a.toSeq
  case other => Seq(other)
}.map{_.toString}
//Seq[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, whatever)
```

(as an aside, this is pretty ugly Scala code, you might want to consider refactoring things to get rid of using a `Seq[Any]` in the first place)

Comment: Or, equivalently: `as.flatMap { ... }.map(_.toString)`.

Comment: Much cleaner, thanks.  What I was really looking for was a way to collapse the Traversable and Array cases into one.  It seems like the implicit conversion of Array to Seq should allow you to do that somehow.

Comment: I agree that the Seq[Any] isn't ideal.  This all grew out of working with Play 2's WS framework, which represents query parameters as a Map[String, String].  Subsequently I wanted to support multi-valued parameters, and so my code actually has a Map[String, Any].

Comment: @TravisBrown good suggestion, not sure why I didn't do that in the first place :/